# Understanding sum of Dirichlet characters

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

I'm trying to understand how Dirichlet Characters work, especially the sum of Dirichlet Characters.
Concerning the definitions, we have:
$\chi : G \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} ^{\times}$ is a homomorphism from a group $G$ to $\mathbb{C} ^{\times}$. These homomorphisms are called characters of $G$. $\widehat{G}$ denotes the set of all characters of $G$.

Now, is it given that $G$ is always cyclic, or are there cases where $G$ is not cyclic?

I have a lemma in my textbook (Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory by Montgomery H.L., Vaughan R.C., lemma 4.2, page 115) that states that for $G$ cyclic og order $n$, and $G$ generated by $a$, there are exactly $n$ characters of $G$, namely $\chi_k(a^m)=e(km/n)$ for $1\leq k \leq n$. But it's not clear to me what the expression $e(km/n)$ means. This is important for me to understand in order to show the rest of the lemma, which states:

$\sum_{g\in G}\chi (g) = \{n \text{ if } \chi=\chi_0 \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise }\} $

and

$\sum_{\chi \in \widehat{G}}\chi (g) = \{n \text{ if } g=e \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise }\} $

$\chi_0$ is the principal character.

If someone knows an easy-to-understand introduction to Dirichlet Characters, please point me in that direction.

Comment: "Dirichlet", not "diriclet". And see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259725/what-are-dirichlet-characters?rq=1), the group $G=(\Bbb Z/n)^{\times}$ need not be cyclic in general.

Comment: You should try with the characters modulo $15$, they are of the form $\chi(a)=0$ if $\gcd(a,15)\ne 1$ and $\chi(11^b 7^c+15d) = e^{2i\pi l b/2}e^{2i\pi m c/4}$ for some integers $l,m$. Those integers $11,7,2,4$ appear because $\Bbb{Z/15Z}^\times = \langle 11\rangle \times \langle 7\rangle \cong \Bbb{Z/2Z \times Z/4Z}$

Comment: So $e(km/n)=e^{2i\pi km/n}$ if I understand correctly? And you say that $\chi_{15}(a)=\chi_{2}(a) \chi_{4}(a)$. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Just trying to understand what you wrote

Comment: Personally, chapter 6 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* offers a friendly introduction to Dirichlet characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\chi$ be an arbitrary character of $G$ and $a$ be $G$'s generator, then we have

$$
\chi(a^n)=1=\chi(a)^n
$$

Since $\chi$ is a homomorphism from $G$ into the complex domain, we know that the above equation has $n$ solutions, each of them being the $n$'th root of unity. Thus using the notation $e(s)=e^{2\pi is}$ we can rewrite the character as

$$
\chi_k(a)=e(k/n)
$$

where $k=0,1,2,\dots,n-1$. This indicates that there are exactly $n$ characters in a cyclic group of order $n$. Moreover, we know that the character maps the group into the unit circle of complex plane.